# What word is missing in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> You yourself being a sportsperson […] know that sports is one of the few things that teaches discipline.

The intended meaning of sentence should be the following: Since you are a sportsperson hence you must have already known that sports is one of the few things that teaches discipline. There must be something before *know*; it's my gut feeling. I think it should be "must already," "already," or "would."

Comment: You would agree, being a sportsperson yourself, that sports teaches discipline.

Comment: @Soulz I am not making someone agree,though your sentence is correct,but I want to convey he should already know it(that sports teaches discipline). Please tell me the word that suits with "know"

Comment: I don't think anything is missing.

Comment: How about 'aware'? 

You must be aware, being a sportsperson yourself, that sports teaches discipline

Comment: @ Sanket Verma: Although your use of "plural treated as singular" ***sports*** is credible, most native speakers would change it to singular ***sport***. To my ear, either is better than saying [that sports are one (of life's many pleasures, or whatever)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that+sports+are+one%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but even that occurs often enough that it must be called "credible" as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually *necessary* to have any other word before "know", but there are a few points to make...

> 1: OP's inclusion of *yourself* is grammatically irrelevant here (it just adds emphasis).
>
> 2: So is the "parenthetical" phrase *being a sportsman* (which could be set off by commas).

---

The alternative "auxiliary" verbs that could optionally go before *know* can carry different implications...

> A: *ought to, should,* etc. - which [may] imply that the speaker *believes/expects* you to know.
> B: *will, would, must,* etc. [or *nothing*] - which imply the speaker *knows* that you know.
> C: *may, might,* etc. - which imply the speaker thinks it's *possible* that you know.

---

For what it's worth, I'll just say that idiomatically probably ***will*** is most likely for OP's exact intended meaning. This may seem a little odd to non-native speakers (why say *you **will** know*, when what you mean is *you **do** know*?) All I can say is native speakers habitually use "future tense" in such statements.

---

The possibility of including *already* is a separate issue. Semantically it adds very little, and it wouldn't normally be there unless the speaker specifically wanted to emphasise *previously-acquired* knowledge affecting *present/future* actions (i.e. - *"You **already** know it, so I won't bother to explain it [again] **now***).

Comment: I actually think *should* is a better fit here than *will*.

Comment: @KenB: Not in OP's exact context, I don't think. He says the person ***must*** know. Although the "obligation/expectation" element of ***should*** could plausibly attach to *the state of affairs as assumed by the speaker*, it more often attaches to the person being addressed. And OP isn't suggesting that the person *ought* to know, he's saying he ***does*** (because he *must*, so it's a foregone conclusion).

Comment: You make a good argument. I think there's a fine line, though. The speaker could easily be expressing his *expectation* or hope that the addressee knows. I think more context is required. For example, consider the case of two fathers chatting about raising their respective children. One has stated that he doesn't want his son playing sports because he is afraid of his son being injured. The other then might respond with "But it builds character! You yourself being a sportsperson should know that sports is one of the few things that teaches discipline." This fit's OP's stated context.

Comment: @KenB: Well, OP's not a native speaker, so we can't read too much into whether he meant *ought to* when he wrote *must*. And even native speakers are often careless of the potential distinction in such constructions. But I hope the A/B/C categories in my answer explain how different choices *may* affect implied meanings.

Answer (score 2):

"Know" works in context. There are different kinds of "knowing". You might know something because of years of careful study, like "Jack knows quantum physics better than Heisenberg." You might know by intuition or common sense, like "You know that young people fall in love." If you think that "know" only applies to the careful-study kind of knowing: No, it doesn't. It is readily understood to mean either kind (and other kinds of knowing).

I think most readers would assume from the context that "know" here refers to knowledge gained from personal experience, or possibly from intuition. When it's really necessary to distinguish, I don't know of a single, commonly-used word that could be substituted. You'd have to either use an obscure word or use a phrase to clarify. Life if you wanted to make clear that Jack's knowledge of physics in fact does not come from years of study but that he just somehow seems to have an intuition about these things, you would say, "Jack knows quantum physics by intuition" or some such.

In your case, you could say, "You know from experience that sports teaches discipline" or "You have seen that sports teaches discipline." You might say, "You intuit that sports teaches discipline" if you insist on using a single word, but that just sounds awkward to me. As I say, I think most readers would take it for granted that you meant knowledge gained from experience or observation, especially with the "as a sportsman" stuck on the front. If your intent was that he knows this because he is read studies in psychology journals of research demonstrating this, then you would need different words to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

> As a sportsperson, you know that sports is one of the few things that teaches discipline.